# Google Play Game Service Achievements Not Loading in Swift IOS Application

Tags: ios, swift, google-play-games

I am trying to implement a Google Play Game Service Achievements in my Swift application. I am new to Swift and IOS programming. I have got as far as presenting the Achievements view controller but when it comes up it just has the loading animation and no achievements are shown. I can not close out of the controller either and I get this error pop up in the console.

`[GPGManager modelForApplicationId:] Expecting valid application id.`

I was following instructions from https://developers.google.com/games/services/ios/achievements

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message I would guess that you did not set the application id, or client id as their docs say applicationId is deprecated.

From the [GPGManager Class reference](https://developers.google.com/games/services/ios/api/interface_g_p_g_manager)

> Use [`signInWithClientID:silently:`](https://developers.google.com/games/services/ios/api/interface_g_p_g_manager) or [`signInWithClientID:silently:withExtraScopes:`](https://developers.google.com/games/services/ios/api/interface_g_p_g_manager.html#af9556ae1820010d05467f6047d270615) for the simplified flow. Use [`signIn`](https://developers.google.com/games/services/ios/api/interface_g_p_g_manager.html#a4737d03100aaf006a5e754336053ddbc) for the advanced flow. See the Sign-in section of the Developer's Guide for details.

Have you signed in before you're presenting the achievement view?